# SSIS package output to CSV file -

Tags: csv, ssis

I have an issue regarding the CSV-output of an SSIS package which returns a query result. The package configuration are set to choose semicolon ';' as column delimiter and this works great in our dev-environment.
But in Test-env. it outputs the csv file with comma-separated columns!

```
Result in Dev env.
Id;Name
1;some name

Result in Test env.
Id, Name
1, some name
```

Is there any explanation for this? I have already checked the Region settings of the test-server and they are exactly the same as the one we have in our dev. env.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, did you verified the property **Column delimiter** in **Columns** tab in your **Flat File Connection Manager**?

Comment: Yes. The property is set to semicolon.

Comment: Is the delimiter being set by a package configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the properties window of the file connection and click on expressions, click on (...) for a new expression.

Here you can select 'Row Delimeter' from the drop-down box under property, then click (...) to create an expression. You can add a user variable that will hold the delimeter to your expression and this should resolve to a valid delimeter.